# Access a DOM element in javascript after it is shown - Svelte

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I'm creating a custom select dropdown component, simplified below:

```
<script lang="ts">
    let optionsOpen: boolean = false;

    function onSelectClick(e) {
        optionsOpen = !optionsOpen;
        let p = e.target.closest('.select');
        let child = p.querySelector('.options');
        console.log(child);  //always null
    }
</script>


<div class="select" on:click={onSelectClick}>
    {#if optionsOpen}
        <div class="options">
            My Options
        </div>
    {/if}
</div>
```

From the above you'll see that when the div with .select class is clicked, the option container opens (via the optionsOpen variable).

However, in the onSelectClick I need to access the options div DOM element once it has been opened.  I can access the select div, but not the child options div, it always returns null.

I suspect it may be because the options element it not yet available when I try to access it, even though I am setting the optionsOpen variable to prior to my attempt to access.

Any ideas how to access the options div after it is made visible?

Comment: For what purpose do you need to access the DOM element?

Comment: The position of the options needs to be adjusted when near the bottom of the window so that the user does not to scroll it into view.  So Basically I need to adjust options.style.top property in the above case

Comment: `tick` might be perfectly acceptable in this case (I haven't used it myself, so I can't make arguments for or against it). As an alternative you could try assigning the DOM element to a local variable via like [`bind:this={optionsElement}`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-component-directives-bind-this) on the element and then do `$: if (optionsOpen && optionsElement) { /* do stuff */ }`.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this, I'll give this a go in addition to the tick function to help me get a broader understanding of how things work in svelte.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way to approach this would be to use a [Svelte action](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action). This is a custom function that runs when a DOM node is added and gives you access to the node directly.

This is more idiomatic than using `querySelector`.

```svelte
<script>
    let optionsOpen = false;

    function onSelectClick(e) {
        optionsOpen = !optionsOpen;
    }
    
    function adjustPosition(node) {
        // this will run when <div class="options"> is added to the DOM
        node.style.top = '300px'; // or whatever you want to do
    }
</script>


<div class="select" on:click={onSelectClick}>
    Select
    {#if optionsOpen}
        <div class="options" use:adjustPosition>
            My Options
        </div>
    {/if}
</div>
```

Comment: An excellent answer, seems like the more native svelte approach which is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by using the tick function, the modified function is below:

```
<script lang="ts">
    let optionsOpen: boolean = false;

    async function onSelectClick(e) {
        optionsOpen = !optionsOpen;
        await tick();
        let p = e.target.closest('.select');
        let child = p.querySelector('.options');
        console.log(child);  //not null anymore
    }
</script>
```

I would be interested in other possible solutions in addition to the above if available and be informed if the above solution is not the correct way to handle such a situation.